# Why lasso cannot be arbitrarily applied?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, lasso, sparse

Consider any log likelihood function $f(\theta|x)$ where $x$ is data. I can consider $f(\theta|x)+\lambda||\theta||_1$ where $||\theta||_1$ is the standard $L_1$ norm.

It seems that I cannot apply this sort of argument naively to obtain sparsity. I found in the following article that conditional "independence" is required. I think conditional independence in this case is equivalent to sparsity. https://tibshirani.su.domains/ftp/graph.pdf

(pg 1)"The basic model for continuous data assumes that the observations have a
multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. If
the $ij$th component of $\Sigma^{-1}$ is zero, then variables $i$ and $j$ are conditionally independent, given the other variables. Thus it makes sense to impose an $L_1$ penalty for the estimation of $\Sigma^{-1}$, to increase sparsity."

I think the paper is used to estimate $\Sigma^{-1}$ which is sparse. Why conditional independence is required to make sense for sparsity by $L_1$? It seems that variables $i$ and $j$ are conditional independent if and only if $ij$th component of $\Sigma^{-1}$ is zero. That is reason why sparsity is expected by conditional independence.

Comment: no that's a misunderstanding. For their application (with gaussian data), having the matrix elements being zero corresponds to conditional independence. For other applications, eg linear regression, it's not related.

Comment: @seanv507 However, if I remember correctly from ESL, the book does mention how to derive ridge case from independence of parameter $\theta$ in regression case. That independence is the assumption to derive degree of freedom in lasso case.

Comment: Should $f(\theta|x)$ not be $f(x|\theta)$?

Comment: @RichardHardy They are same thing under maximum likelihood without Bayesian view. They maybe completely different under Bayesian if one uses prior.

Comment: I think that from a frequentist perspective, $f(\theta|x)$ is not meaningful, as a parameter does not have a probability density function.

Comment: @RichardHardy It is from frequentist perspective, $f(\theta|x)$ is not density.

Comment: @user45765, I agree. It is not a meaningful object from a frequentist perspective. I still wonder under what school of thought, except for the Bayesian one, it is a meaningful object. (We have already covered that even if it is not meaningless for Bayesians, this is not the likelihood that is used in Bayesian updating; the latter one is $f(x|\theta)$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found in the following article that conditional "independence" is required.

This condition relates to a different issue which is specific to the application in that article.

It is not a condition that is necessary in order to be able to apply a L1 norm to obtain sparsity.

That idea of independence relates to the model

> The basic model for continuous data assumes that the observations have a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$

For this model independence between components $i$ and $j$ is equivalent to zero covariance $\Sigma_{ij}$ (and those covariance terms is what is being estimated in this specific case).

The zero's $\Sigma_{ij}$ are a *motivation* to use estimation of the $\hat\Sigma_{ij}$ with an L1-norm regularisation. But for different problems, where not the parameters $\Sigma_{ij}$ are being estimated but something else, it will not be necessary and we would expect the sparsity to be present in some other way.